# Why $k[x_{0},x_{1},x_{2}]/(x_{0}+x_{1}+x_{2}-1)\xrightarrow{\cong}k[y_{0},y_{1}]$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, binomial-theorem

Let $k$ be a field. I am trying to prove the following isomorphism
$$f\colon k[x_{0},x_{1},x_{2}]/I\xrightarrow{\cong}k[y_{0},y_{1}]$$

where $I=(x_{0}+x_{1}+x_{2}-1)$ and $$f(x)=\begin{cases}y_{0},&\text{if $x=x_{0}$}\\
y_{1},&\text{if $x=x_{1}$}\\1-y_{0}-y_{1},&\text{if $x=x_{2}$}\end{cases}$$

I can prove that it is well-defined and epimorphism. I am stuck at injectivity (I want to prove it rigorously). First, by the formula we have $I\subseteq \ker(f)$. Let $h(x_{0},x_1,x_2)\in\ker(f)$. Then we can write $h(x_0,x_1,x_2)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}g_{i}(x_0,x_1)x_{2}^{i}$. We have,
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}g_{i}(y_0,y_1)(1-y_{0}-y_1)^{i}=0$$
Then, we can write
$$0=\sum_{i=0}^{n}g_{i}(y_0,y_1)(1-y_{0}-y_1-y_2+y_2)^{i}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}g_{i}(y_0,y_1)\sum_{k=0}^{i}\binom{i}{k}(1-y_{0}-y_1-y_2)^{i-k}y_{2}^{k}=$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}g_{i}(y_0,y_1)\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}\binom{i}{k}(1-y_{0}-y_1-y_2)^{i-k}y_{2}^{k}+h(y_1,y_2,y_3)$$
and hence $h\in\ker(f)$. Is there a more efficient way to prove injectivity? Is my argument rigorous?

Comment: Perhaps a somewhat faster approach to prove that $f$ is an isomorphism would be to show that $f$ has an inverse. In this case the inverse is the map $f’:k[y_0,y_1]\to k[x_0,x_1,x_2]/I$ taking $y_0\mapsto x_0$ and $y_1\mapsto x_1$. It doesn’t take much work to prove this is the inverse (the composites $ff’$ and $f’f$ are the identity maps because they each fix a generating set).